# MYSQL query using calculated variables

Tags: mysql

In the following MYSQL is there a way to use the intermediate variables `received` and `refund` to calculate the `net` rather than re-expressing them in the longhand query form?

```
SELECT reservations.id as reservationid, `gh`, `gh-br2`, `gh-loft`, `gh-br3`, `mh-br1`, `mh-br2`, `mh-all`,
              `deposit_amnt` + `pet_deposit` AS deposit, pet_fee, damage_insurance, cleaning_fee, deposit_refund_amnt, rental_amnt,
              otherFees, tax_total as tax, beginDate, endDate, rental_total, phoneNum, cellPhoneNum, email, concat(firstName,' ',lastName) AS name,
    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount),0.0) FROM payments WHERE reservation_id = reservations.id AND payments.type = 'received') AS received,
    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount),0.0) FROM payments WHERE reservation_id = reservations.id AND payments.type = 'refunded') AS refund,
    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount),0.0) FROM payments WHERE reservation_id = reservations.id AND payments.type = 'received') -
    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount),0.0) FROM payments WHERE reservation_id = reservations.id AND payments.type = 'refunded') AS net
    FROM (visitors, reservations)
    WHERE (reservations.visitorCode = visitors.id AND reservations.status = 'confirmed') $queryYear $queryCash
    ORDER BY $sortBy $_SESSION[sort_order]
```

Comment: There is (wrap it in a subquery) - but there's no real advantage performance-wise. AND PLEASE DON'T USE '-' in column names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can really fix up this query!  First, learn about explicit join syntax (the use of the `join` and `on` keywords).  Second, you don't need all those subqueries.  You can move the logic into the `from` clause.  Here is an alternative form for your query:

```
SELECT r.id as reservationid, `gh`, `gh-br2`, `gh-loft`, `gh-br3`, `mh-br1`, `mh-br2`, `mh-all`,
       (`deposit_amnt` + `pet_deposit`) AS deposit, pet_fee, damage_insurance, cleaning_fee,
       deposit_refund_amnt, rental_amnt,
       otherFees, tax_total as tax, beginDate, endDate, rental_total,
       phoneNum, cellPhoneNum, email, concat(firstName, ' ', lastName) AS name,
       p.received, p.refund, p.net
FROM visitors v join
     reservations r
     on r.visitorCode = v.id left join
     (select reservation_id,
             sum(case when p.type = 'received' then amount else 0 end) as received,
             sum(case when p.type = 'refunded' then amount else 0 end) as refunded,
             (sum(case when p.type = 'received' then amount else 0 end) -
              sum(case when p.type = 'refunded' then amount else 0 end)
             ) as net
      from payments
      group by reservation_id
     ) p
     on p.reservation_id = r.id
WHERE (r.status = 'confirmed') $queryYear $queryCash
ORDER BY $sortBy $_SESSION[sort_order]
```